# Matrix results comparison

Tags: powerbi

I have the following situation to raise on a board and I don't know how to do it or if it is possible. the board would have to have 4 segmenters "Year A", "Months A", "Year B", "Months B".
I have a calendar table and another one of accounting entries, which has the fields date, account, amount.

my scenario is the following i need to try to get you to select a year and months in which
segmenters A = Year(2022) Months(October,November,December) and different ones in segmenters B = Year(2022) Months(July,August)

and generate a table as follows

account segment A Segment B Address
1              100               120         20
2                50                60         10
3                60                50        -10
5                99               600        501

solution suggestions